# How to install and set new themes in KDE plasma via terminal

Tags: command-line, kde, theme

I've been having some issues with the breeze theme while starting plasma and I want to know if there is a way to install a another plasma theme via the terminal and set that to default.
I'm using arch linux.

Comment: It would be good to know if you have a prefered theme. There are a lot in the AUR and even in the official repositories.

Comment: @C.W. I don't need a specific theme just need to make the de usable (which isn't for me). But if you want  a name, then maybe Arch-Dark seems good.

Comment: did my suggestion it help?

Comment: @C.W. I was able to fix it by reinstalling the complete plasma package. But you're answer did teach me some new stuff. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

1. change your working directory to the place where you want to download the package at.
2. download a tarball and extract it. Both is done with the command `curl -L -O https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/arc-dark-suite.tar.gz`
3. use `ls` to get a list of all files in the directory
4. change the directory to the extracted folder `cd arc-dark-suite`
5. now run `makepkg -si` . The command `-si` automatically resolves and install any dependencies with pacman before building and installs the package if it is built successfully.

Now do you use SDDM (The Simple Desktop Display Manager)? If yes fine, if not you should. It is the preferred display manager for KDE Plasma desktops.

Open the config file with `sudo nano /etc/sddm.conf` to be able to change things in there. Scroll to the Theme section and set arc-dark-suite as default (instead of breeze).